# VBA:: Exiting loops

Tags: vba, for-loop

I am creating a search function that loops through a 1 dimensional array looking for answers specified by the user and my problem currently is that I only want the search to loop through the searched range once.  However, it is currently stuck in the loop.  Is there any suggestions on how I can exit this loop after it searches through the function once? I have currently the following code below.  I am storing the cell addresses in the Results1() array and I only want each found term to be stored once

P1B1 is a radio button that specifies the function to search through the data range for any values less than the specified (Textbox1) value.  FindRange1 is the range of data values I want the function to search through.

```
Dim Results1() As Variant
Dim Find1 As Range
Dim FindRange1 As Range
Dim TextBox1 As Long
Dim i1 As Long

            Set FindRange1 = Worksheets("Properties").Range("P7:P1000")
            If ILsearch.P1B1.Value = True Then
                For i1 = 0 To Max
                    For Each Find1 In FindRange1
                        If (Find1.Value < TextBox1) And (Find1.Value > 0) Then
                            i1 = i1 + 1
                            ReDim Preserve Results1(i1)
                            Results1(i1) = Find1.Address
                        End If
                    Next Find1
                Next i1
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid for the `For i1=0 to Max` loop - judging by your requirements it is not needed, as you only seem to want to visit every element in `FindRange1` once.

Comment: A solution would be to use Option Base 1

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a matter of only looping through the range, rather than looping through the array as well. Note that modifiying a loop variable (`i1` in your code) is usually not a smart thing to do.

```
Dim Results1() As Variant
Dim Find1 As Range
Dim FindRange1 As Range
Dim TextBox1 As Long
Dim i1 As Long

    Set FindRange1 = Worksheets("Properties").Range("P7:P1000")
    If ILsearch.P1B1.Value = True Then
        i1 = 0
        For Each Find1 In FindRange1
            If (Find1.Value < TextBox1) And (Find1.Value > 0) Then
                i1 = i1 + 1                      ' increase results upper bound by 1
                ReDim Preserve Results1(1 to i1) ' extend array 
                Results1(i1) = Find1.Address     ' store the new found value
            End If
        Next
    End If
```